# Can we see the data model in the tableau like table viewer option show in QlikView?

Tags: datamodel

I wants to see the data model in my report can I see the data model like the QlikView there is the option available tableviewer. I am searching for this type of feature in Tableau.

Thanks and Regards
Surbhi Sahu
Business Intelligence Solution Provider
www.bispsolutions.com

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot see the data model in tableau like the way you see it in qlikview .

Data modelling maybe completely handled by some other tool of choice in tableau.